# Why does Imu want to hide his/her existence?

Tags: one-piece

Although **Gorosei** told everyone that no one reigns on the Empty Throne during reverie , *Imu* is the current holder of the Empty Throne.

Answer (score -1):

i think if it gets public the balance and equilibrium will end and there would be huge fights between the WG and pirates+rebel+other outlawns

Comment: Many of the WG, marines(sword), and many if not all the kingdoms,  would join the revolutionaries as well. As they feel the current system is just and honest.